# The Sleeping Professor Problem in Threads Synchronization using c language

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

the code isn't working for some reason

> Once class is over, professors like to sleep — except when students
> bother them to answer  questions. You have to write procedures to
> synchronize threads representing one professor and  an arbitrary
> number of students. A professor with nothing to do calls IdleProf(),
> which checks to see if a student is waiting  outside the office to ask
> a question. IdleProf sleeps if there are no students waiting;
> otherwise, it  signals one student to enter the office, and returns. A
> student with a question to ask calls  ArrivingStudent(), which joins
> the queue of students waiting outside the office for a signal from
> the professor; if no students are waiting, then the student wakes up
> the sleeping professor. The  idea is that the professor and exactly
> one student will return from their respective functions “at  the same
> time”: after returning they discuss a topic of mutual interest, then
> the student goes back  to studying and the professor calls IdleProf
> again.  Implement IdleProf and ArrivingStudent using mutexes and
> condition variables. You  may assume that mutexes and condition
> variables are fair (e.g., FIFO).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex; pthread_cond_t prof,stud; int busy = 1; int std_nb = 0;

void *IdleProf() {
    //prof sleeping
    busy = 0;
    while(1){
        if(std_nb == 0) {
            printf("Professor is sleeping");
            pthread_cond_wait(&stud, &mutex);

        }
        else {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            busy = 1;
            printf("Professor is busy ");
            std_nb--;
            pthread_cond_signal(&prof);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    } }

void *ArrivingStudents() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(busy == 0 && std_nb == 0) {
        busy = 1;
         // Waking up the Prof
        pthread_cond_signal(&stud);
        printf("Professor woke up ");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    else {
        std_nb++;
        //wait for students
        pthread_cond_wait(&prof,&mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }


}


int main() {
    printf("Students Number?: ");
    scanf("%d",std_nb);
    pthread_t *thread;
    thread = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*std_nb);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&prof,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&stud,NULL);
    for(int i=0;i<std_nb;i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,IdleProf,NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<std_nb;i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,ArrivingStudents,NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<std_nb;i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&prof);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&stud);
    pthread_exit(NULL); }
```

Comment: Lines 44 and 49 --- https://godbolt.org/z/o843qfcn4

Comment: yeah this, but I meant if the conditions are in the right position

Comment: `IdleProf()` and `ArrivingStudent()` are functions that the threads must call at appropriate times, but they do not encompass the full behavior of the professor and the students as described in the exercise, therefore they cannot be the entry point functions for your threads.

Comment: In fact, the exercise does not appear to be asking you to write the threads' entry point functions at all, but rather only the `IdleProf()` and `ArrivingStudent()` functions, which implement (only) the synchronization between threads.  You probably need your own example thread functions for testing, but those do not appear to be part of the assignment.

Comment: So, reading the exercise carefully, `IdleProf()` dequeues one waiting student, blocking until it can do so.  `ArrivingStudents()` enqueues one student, and blocks until that student is dequeued.  You don't need an actual queue, however, because you are allowed to rely on your mutex(es) and CV(s) to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you need to consider two conditions.
The professor must sleep until the queue of students exceeds 0.
The professor must resume sleeping when the queue of students equals 0 and the professor is not in discussion with a student (is available).
Each student must wait in the queue until that student is at the head of the queue and the professor is available.

To make the problem more interesting, each conference between the professor and a student can take a different amount of time.

Following is a solution written using the Ada programming language.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;               use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;       use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Float_Random; use Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;

procedure Main is
   protected student_queue is
      entry Idle_Prof;
      entry Arriving_Student (Num : Positive);
      procedure Toggle_Prof_Available;
   private
      Prof_Available : Boolean := True;
   end student_queue;

   protected body student_queue is
      entry Idle_Prof when Arriving_Student'Count > 0 is
      begin
         null;
      end Idle_Prof;

      entry Arriving_Student (Num : Positive) when Prof_Available is
      begin
         Prof_Available := False;
         Put_Line ("Professor in conference with student." & Num'Image);
      end Arriving_Student;

      procedure Toggle_Prof_Available is
      begin
         Prof_Available := True;
      end Toggle_Prof_Available;

   end student_queue;

   task type Student is
      entry See_Professor (Num : Positive);
   end Student;

   task Professor is
      entry Start;
      entry Done;
   end Professor;

   task body Student is
      Id   : Positive;
      Seed : Generator;
   begin
      Reset (Seed);
      accept See_Professor (num : Positive) do
         Id := num;
      end See_Professor;

      student_queue.Arriving_Student (Id);
      delay (Duration (Random (Seed)));
      student_queue.Toggle_Prof_Available;
   end Student;

   task body Professor is
      sleeping : Boolean := True;
   begin
      accept Start;
      loop
         select
            accept Done;
            exit;
         else
            select
               student_queue.Idle_Prof;
               sleeping := True;
            else
               if sleeping then
                  Put_Line ("Professor sleeping.");
               end if;
               sleeping := False;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Professor;

   type Student_list is array (Positive range <>) of Student;

   Num_students : Positive;

begin
   Put ("Enter the number of students: ");
   Get (Num_students);
   declare
      Students : array (1 .. Num_students) of Student;
   begin
      Professor.Start;
      for I in Students'Range loop
         Students (I).See_Professor (I);
         delay 0.001;
      end loop;
   end;
   Professor.Done;
end Main;
```

This solution uses an Ada protected object, which implements a Hoare Monitor. [Protected object description](https://files.adacore.com/gnat-book/node17.htm)

A protected object is implemented in two parts. The protected object specification defines both the API for the protected object and any private data members of the protected object. The protected body implements the operations defined as the API of the protected object.

The protected object named student_queue implements two protected entries and one protected procedure. In the body for student_queue we see that the entry Idle_Prof contains the condition *Arriving_Student'Count > 0*. Since protected entries can block a calling task the blocked tasks are implicitly placed in an entry queue. This expression simply evaluates the number of tasks waiting in the entry queue associated with the entry Arriving_Student. The purpose of Idle_Prof is to suspend Professor until a student enters the queue.

The entry Arriving_Student has a condition Prof_Available which is true whenever the professor is not in conference with a student.

The protected procedure Toggle_Prof_Available provides an API so that the Student task in conference with the Professor can set the Prof_Available data member of student_queue to TRUE after spending a random time with the Professor.

One Ada task is declared for the Professor and an Ada task type is declared for the student. The task type allows an arbitrary number of instances of a student task to be created.

Ada tasks can have entries, allowing tasks to synchronously communicate directly with other tasks. The Professor task has two entries named Start and Done. The Start entry causes the Professor to suspend until the program is ready to implement conferences between the Professor and an arbitrary number of Student tasks. The Done entry is used to signal the Professor task to terminate.

The Student task type body implements the behavior of the student. The accept statement in the Student task body causes the task instance to suspend until its See_Professor entry is called, passing a student number to the student task. The Student instance then calls student_queue.Arriving_Student, passing its ID number. The task will suspend in the Arriving_Student entry queue until that task instance is at the head of the queue and Professor is available. After executing the Arriving_Student protected entry the Student instance delays (similar to a C sleep) for a random time between 0.0 and 1.0 seconds. After the delay expires the Student task calls Toggle_Prof_Available to make the Professor available to another Student instance. Finally, the Student task instance terminates.

The Professor task waits at the *Accept Start* statement so that it will wait until the main task calls Professor.Start. The Professor task then enters an infinite loop that is only terminated when the main task calls Professor.Done. Each time through the loop the Professor task conditionally accepts the Done entry, and if it has not yet been called, the Professor task calls Student_Queue.Idle_Prof. If that entry call is not immediately handled the Professor task output the string "Professor sleeping." and repeats its internal loop iteration.

The main thread declares an unconstrained array type named Student_List which is an array of Student tasks. It also declares a variable Num_Students which will hold an integer greater than 0 which will be entered by the user.

The user is prompted for the number of students and the user input is assigned to Num_Students.

An internal block is defined. In the declarative section of the block an instance of Student_List named Students is created with the number of elements specified by the user input.

Professor.Start is called, causing the Professor to start sleeping and/or conferencing with waiting students. A loop incrementing through the Students array calls See_Professor, setting the Student ID to the index of that element in the array. A delay of 0.001 seconds is called to ensure that Operating System scheduling allows the Student tasks to be handled in the expected order.

The use of the internal block has the effect of a pthreads join call on all the Student tasks. The internal block will not complete until all the Student threads are complete.

Finally the main task calls Professor.Done and the program terminates.

A sample execution of the program is:

```
Enter the number of students: 7
Professor sleeping.
Professor in conference with student. 1
Professor in conference with student. 2
Professor in conference with student. 3
Professor in conference with student. 4
Professor in conference with student. 5
Professor in conference with student. 6
Professor in conference with student. 7
Professor sleeping.
```